# Maximum common divider for two numbers on Python

Tags: python, for-loop, ident

I need help to check a little code:

```
def mcd(n1,n2):
  mxcd = 0
  for i in range(1,n1):  
    f = n1 % i  
    for j in range(1,n2):
      g = n2 % j 
      if (f == 0 and g == 0 and f == g): 
        mxcd = f  
      else: 
        mxcd = "No hay comun divisor"
  return mxcd
```

I have problems because it seems it never enters the first `if`, It always enters the `else`, I've tried changing the indentation orders, taking out the `if` from the second `for` but it's not working. If someone could help that would be great.

Comment: Well even if you do find a common divisor, in the next iteration of the loop, you are just overriding it with the string "No hay ...". This is a very simple logic error. Try replacing the lines `mxcd = f` and `mxcd = "No hay ..."` with print statements to see the issue

Comment: Try using more descriptive names, it may help make the problem stick out more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if` statement logic is off.

You want:

```
if (f==0 and g==0 and i==j):
    mxcd = i
```

Do you see why that is?

There are several other things wrong with this function but that’s why the `if` isn’t working.

Answer (score 0):

You could start by printing out the state of `f` and `g` to see why you don't get anything happening in the `if` statement.

```
def mcd(n1,n2):
  mxcd = 0
  for i in range(1,n1):
    f = n1 % i
    print('i is {}, f is {}'.format(i, f))
    for j in range(1,n2):
      g = n2 % j
      print('\n  j is {}, g is {}'.format(j, g))
      if (f == 0 and g == 0 and f == g): 
        mxcd = f  
      else: 
        mxcd = "No hay comun divisor"
  return mxcd
```

running something like `mcd(2,4)` lets you know a lot:

```
i is 1, f is 0
  j is 1, g is 0  
  j is 2, g is 0    
  j is 3, g is 1
'No hay comun divisor'
```

You *do* open the `if` statement, which you can see by using a similar trick:

```
def mcd(n1,n2):
  mxcd = 0
  for i in range(1,n1):  
    f = n1 % i  
    for j in range(1,n2):
      g = n2 % j 
      if (f == 0 and g == 0 and f == g): 
        print('hello')
        mxcd = f  
      else: 
        mxcd = "No hay comun divisor"
  return mxcd 

> mcd(4,8)

hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
'No hay comun divisor'
```

From there, you have a few issues to correct to get the right answer but I'll leave that exercise to you :)